# Função para retornar total de vendas

Tags: sql, funções

Tenho essa função que me retorna a quantidade de vendas de um cnpj mês á mês no ano de 2018, gostaria se possível que alguém me ajudasse a implementar uma variável nesta função, que pegasse o total por cnpj no ano e mostrar como uma coluna em um select.

```
ALTER FUNCTION totalDeTransmissoesNoMes(  
    @cnpjDaRevenda VARCHAR(15),  
    @ano int,  
    @mes int  
)RETURNS int AS BEGIN DECLARE @totalDeTransmissoes int;  

SET @totalDeTransmissoes = (  
    SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM enviovendas as ei  
    WHERE ei.ds_cnpjrev = @cnpjDaRevenda   
    AND YEAR(ei.dt_envio) = @ano  
    AND MONTH(ei.dt_envio) = @mes  
);   
RETURN @totalDeTransmissoes;  
END;
```

Comment: Você quer fazer outra função ou nessa mesmo?

Comment: Olá Marconi tudo bem? eu fiz uma outra função, mas eu preciso é tentar fazer na mesma função.